Question on apex trigger scenario
I wrote this code for the following scenario and the scenario is:

Once an Account will update
then that Account will update with the total amount from All its Opportunities on the Account Level
The account field name would be "Total Opportunity Amount"

trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
         AccountTriggerHandler.afterupdate(Trigger.New);
    }
}

public class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static void afterupdate(List<Account> newList){
         Set<Id> setOfAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

        // Storing the account Ids to query the related opportunity later on.
        for (Account eachAccount : newList) {
            setOfAccountIds.add(eachAccount.Id); // This adds accountId into the set of the account.
        }
        System.debug('setOfAccountIds: ' + setOfAccountIds);

        // Querying related opportunities to an Account and storing it into a list.
        List<Opportunity> lstOfOpportunities = [SELECT Amount, AccountId 
                                                FROM Opportunity 
                                                WHERE AccountId IN :setOfAccountIds];

        // Map to store total Opportunity amount per account
        Map<Id, Decimal> mapOfIdvsDecimal = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

        // Iterating over opportunities to calculate total amount for each Account
        for (Opportunity eachOpportunity : lstOfOpportunities) {
            if (mapOfIdvsDecimal.containsKey(eachOpportunity.AccountId)) {
                mapOfIdvsDecimal.put(eachOpportunity.AccountId, mapOfIdvsDecimal.get(eachOpportunity.AccountId) + eachOpportunity.Amount);
            } else {
                mapOfIdvsDecimal.put(eachOpportunity.AccountId, eachOpportunity.Amount);
            }
        }

        // List to hold accounts to update
        List<Account> lstOfAccountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        // Prepare accounts with updated total opportunity amount
        for (Account eachAccount : newList) {
            Account accToUpdate = new Account(Id = eachAccount.Id); // Create a new instance to update
            if (mapOfIdvsDecimal.containsKey(eachAccount.Id)) {
                accToUpdate.Total_Opportunity_Amount__c = mapOfIdvsDecimal.get(eachAccount.Id);
            } else {
                accToUpdate.Total_Opportunity_Amount__c = 0; // Set to 0 if no opportunities are found
            }
            lstOfAccountsToUpdate.add(accToUpdate);
        }

        // Update accounts
        if (!lstOfAccountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update lstOfAccountsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}

But I'm getting error and the error is

AccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001Qy00000TF37NIAT; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AccountTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate Account trigger event AfterUpdate: [] Class.AccountTriggerHandler.afterupdate: line 44, column 1 Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 3, column 1


This is something that you should use a rollup summary field for instead of a trigger. In general, it's better to use standard features than to write code/make customizations.

Quick (and best) solution: Use a Rollup Summary Field Instead
Like I said in my comment, this is really a scenario that you should be using a rollup summary field for. It's a standard tool, and it's available to be used (unlike the relationship between Account and Contact, which can't have a rollup summary field for because... reasons?).
Why spend the time to make a hammer yourself when Salesforce already provides you with a hammer?
The issue
Setting that aside, the issue you're running into is that you have a recursive update.

An account gets updated from somewhere (the web UI, an API call, other code, etc...)
Your trigger runs
You perform a DML update on the same records that are in the trigger context variables (trigger.new, trigger.newMap, trigger.old, trigger.oldMap)
You re-enter your trigger
The update happens again
You've created an infinite loop (but Salesforce detects that, halts execution, and throws an error)

The issue here is the update lstOfAccountsToUpdate; at the end of your code
The fix
There are a few ways that you could handle that, but the simplest and most appropriate (outside of doing this with a rollup summary field) would be to use a before trigger instead of an after trigger.
The "Before" trigger context is useful when you want to make changes to record(s) that are going through a trigger.
You're trying to make a change to the same Accounts that are being updated
Therefore you should be using a before trigger
A before trigger doesn't need DML to persist the changes. As long as you make the change to the same in-memory instance of the record contained in trigger.new or trigger.newMap, the fields you alter will be persisted without DML.
No DML => no infinite loop, problem solved.
Supposing that you did convert this into a before trigger (but seriously, just use a rollup summary field), aside from the DML statement that should be eliminated, the problematic line in your code is
Account accToUpdate = new Account(Id = eachAccount.Id);
That creates a new, separate in-memory instance of the account that you're working on. That would break the functionality of the before update trigger that allows us to not perform DML.
Just use eachAccount inside of that loop. Do a wholesale find-replace of accToUpdate to eachAccount. Since the loop variable is being fed by a trigger context variable, it's the same instance of the account.
modify data on the same instance of the SObject that the trigger context variables reference, and you don't need to perform DML.
Once again, just use a rollup summary field
and while I'm still here, the check for an empty list before performing DML is unnecessary.
Salesforce does that check for you, and won't count against the DML statements or DML rows limits if the list is empty.
...but again again, you shouldn't be using DML here (or even a trigger)
use a rollup summary field
